# Accessibility WAVE scan on asp.net menu shows errors

Tags: asp.net, accessibility

We're doing a [WAVE](https://webaim.org/) scan of our application to detect accessibility issues. One that I'm looking at now is the "Device dependent event handler". These are shown on the asp:Menu controls. What seems to be the relevant messages says: "an onmouseover event but not an onfocus event". When I look at the page source I do see the generated html like:

```
<td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="ctl00_MainMenun4">
```

This suggests to me that it needs an onfocus event handler that does the same as the onmouseover handler. Am I correct in this assumption. Is there a way to get asp.net to generate this or can/should I look at a way to manually inject this? If the latter, any suggestions?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. See [this MS article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227996.aspx). For the asp:Menu controls I needed to set the Menu's RenderingMode to MenuRenderingMode.List and change the pages element in the web.config controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0".

Answer (score 0):

Adding an onfocus event handler is not sufficient to make the table cell accessible. Table cells are not focusable elements. ([Focusable elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus) are usually `a` elements with an `href` attribute, `link` elements with an `href` attribute, `button`, `input` when `type` is not "hidden", `select` and `textarea`.)

In order to make other elements focusable, you should set the [`tabindex` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex) to "0". This will put the `td` element in your example in the tabbing order and make it reachable with a keyboard. If it can receive keyboard focus, it will also be able to fire the focus event that your listener will be waiting for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you suggest is part of the WAVE suggestions as well. I can add a tabindex="0" to the asp:Menu element, but it does not seem to make any difference. The page source does not get a tabindex, nor does it change the errors that WAVE shows. The individual asp:MenuItem elements will not take a tabindex so I cannot add them there.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="ctl00_MainMenun4">
> ```
>
> This suggests to me that it needs an onfocus event handler that does the same as the onmouseover handler. Am I correct in this assumption. Is there a way to get asp.net to generate this

It depends on what is inside your `td`

For instance, you can perfectly have:

```
<td onmouseover="func_somewhat()"><a href="example.htm">Click</a></td>
```

Putting `onfocus` and `tabindex` on the `td` element will lead to accessibility problem due to the fact that the element itself contains a tabable element.

And this code might be plainly accessible, as long as selecting the inner link with the keyboard permit to achieve what you are expecting.

If the element inside the `td` does not have any focusable element, then you may add the `onfocus` event handler on the `td` itself but you have to satisfy more conditions :

- the `td` should be focusable (`tabindex`)
- the `td` should be indicated as being a `role=button` or `role=link` depending on the lead action
- the `table` should have a `presentation` role if it's used for presentation (which is apparently the case here)